# Directive bi-directional binding chrome/firefox

Tags: angularjs

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/uxle5qgwidGRU3Tgqamc/

http://plnkr.co/edit/uxle5qgwidGRU3Tgqamc?p=preview

I'm trying to create a directive for submit/reset buttons on my forms.
However i'm unable to propagate my controller model into my directive after a 'hard reset' of the object.

I have a timer that in 5 seconds overrides the initial object.

In chrome it works correctly but in firefox after the object is set it shows as undefined in the directive.

please review the console output to see the log i've put in place.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of your problem but you're missing $ in front of `watch` on line 49. Should be `$scope.$watch('Model', function () {`

Comment: Jonathan - that fixed it!